# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: error creating bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, hibernate-mapping

I'm creating an ecommerce website using springMVC and hibernate. How ever I'm getting the following errors while running the junit test case. I'd really appreciate any help provided for the same.

-----------Exception Trace-----------

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Product.category in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Category.product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.AccountDaoTest.initialize(AccountDaoTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:49)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:36)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Product.category in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Category.product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Product.category in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Category.product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Product.category in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Category.product
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.config.HibernateConfig.sessionFactory(HibernateConfig.java:32)
```

Here is the junit test file

AccountDaoTest.java:

```
 package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.dao.AccountDao;
import com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Account;

public class AccountDaoTest {

    @Autowired 
    static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
static AccountDao acDao;
@BeforeClass
public static void initialize() {

    context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.scan("com.yusufjk");
    context.refresh();

    acDao= (AccountDao)context.getBean("userDao");
}
@Test
public void accountTestCase() {

    Account account=new Account();
    account.setUid(1);
    account.setUname("yusufjk");
    account.setRole("admin");
    account.setUemail("nnoreply54@gmail.com");
    account.setUpassword("12345");  
assertEquals(account.getUid(), account.getUid());
}
}
```

HibernateConfig.java:

```
    package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.config;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;



    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan( "com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend" )

    public class HibernateConfig {

        @Autowired 
        @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
        public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
            LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
            sessionFactory.addProperties(hibernateProperties());
            sessionFactory.scanPackages("com.yusufjk");
            return sessionFactory.buildSessionFactory();
         }


        @Autowired
        @Bean(name="datasource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            System.out.println("inside dataSource");
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/devOps");
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("sa");
            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            System.out.println("inside hibernateProperties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
            properties.put("hibernate.format_sql","true");
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
            return properties;        
        }


        @Bean(name="transactionManager")
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
            System.out.println("inside transactionManager");
           HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
           txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
           return txManager;
        }
    }
```

AccountDaoImpl.java:

```
    package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.daoImpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.dao.AccountDao;
import com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Account;


@Repository(value ="userDao")
@Transactional
public class AccountDaoImpl implements AccountDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void InsertUser(Account account) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        session.save(account);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();        
    }

    public Account getUserById(int userId) {

        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Account account = session.load(Account.class, userId);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return account;
        }

    public Account getUserByName(String userName) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Account account =session.load(Account.class, userName);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return account;
    }

    public Account getUserByEmail(String email) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Account account =session.load(Account.class, email);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return account;
        }

}
```

These are the entity classes which might be the cause of the error:

Product.java

```
    package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {

    private String pId;
    private String pName;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Product() {
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Product_Code", length = 10, nullable = false)
    public String getpId() {
        return pId;
    }
    public void setpId(String pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }
    @Column(name = "Product_Name", length = 255, nullable = false)
    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }
    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }
    @Column(name = "Price", nullable = false)
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    @Column(name = "Quantity", nullable = false)
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="cid")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="supplierID")
    private Supplier supplier;
}
```

Category.java

```
    package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Entity
@Table
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cid;

private String cname;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="category")
private Set<Product> product;

public Set<Product> getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Set<Product> product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public String getCname() {
    return cname;
}

public void setCname(String cname) {
this.cname = cname;
}

public int getCid() {
    return cid;
}

public void setCid(int cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}
}
```

But I am not creating the test case for either of them I don't know why it is showing error for these entities. I'm only creating the test case for Account entity so I'll share that as well.

Account.java

```
  package com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Accounts")
public class Account{
      @Id 
      @Email
        private String uemail; 
        @GeneratedValue
        private int uid;

        @NotNull
        private String uname;
        @NotNull
        private String upassword;

        private String role;    

        public  String getRole() {
            return role;
        }
        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
        public String getUemail() {
            return uemail;
        }
        public void setUemail(String uemail) {
            this.uemail = uemail;
        }
        public int getUid() {
            return uid;
        }
        public void setUid(int uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
        }
        public String getUname() {
            return uname;
        }
        public void setUname(String uname) {
            this.uname = uname;
        }
        public String getUpassword() {
            return upassword;
        }
        public void setUpassword(String upassword) {
            this.upassword = upassword;
        }

}
```

Comment: Issue seems to be this, Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Product.category in com.yusufjk.GrocersBasketBackend.domain.Category.product    Can you share your entity classes which are referred in this exception

Comment: Okay I've updated my question with the entity classes. Please go through and help me out if you find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` so Spring can inject your beans to your tests.

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AccountDaoTest {
 //...
}
```

I believe you can inject your dao directly, once you indicated it as a repository, so you can inject your dao instead of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in your test class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDao")
private AccountDaoImpl userDao;
```

And finally, make sure you have `spring-test` in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okay I will try this but where do I have to use this code?------------@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDao")
private AccountDaoImpl userDao;

Comment: Inside your AccountDaoTest, instead of `@Autowired 
    static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;`

Comment: Okay I resolved it, I had to uninstall the mySQL database. It was working perfectly with mySQL and when I uninstalled it, it worked with h2. Thanks for the help!